# SendInput() and non-English characters and keyboard layouts

Tags: windows, unicode, keyboard-events, keyboard-layout

I'm having trouble simulating character keypresses when a non-English input keyboard language is being used in Windows.

I tried calling SendInput() with KEYEVENTF_UNICODE:

```
KEYBDINPUT ki;
INPUT input;
int character = 0;

ki.wVk = 0;
ki.wScan = character;
ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
ki.time = 0;
ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;   
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki = ki;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

And this actually works (of course, in my code, I also do a KEYUP after the key down)... except in GTK+ apps (there may be other instances where it doesn't work either).

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271%28VS.85%29.aspx), *If KEYEVENTF_UNICODE is specified, SendInput sends a WM_KEYDOWN or WM_KEYUP message to the foreground thread's message queue with wParam equal to VK_PACKET. Once GetMessage or PeekMessage obtains this message, passing the message to TranslateMessage posts a WM_CHAR message with the Unicode character originally specified by wScan. This Unicode character will automatically be converted to the appropriate ANSI value if it is posted to an ANSI window.*

So I believe that when KEYEVENTF_UNICODE is passed, the functionality of SendInput() is different... not as low-level as it usually is.

For the life of me, I can't figure out any other way to get SendInput() to print out characters properly for the user's keyboard language. For example, if the keyboard input language is "Swedish", I can't get it to output '@' (instead, it prints out a quotation mark), and I can't get it to output non-ASCII characters properly, either (accented letters, etc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's this, C? C++? C#?

Comment: @Carl: I'm using C, though any example in any language -- so long as it used Win32 API calls -- would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that the proper way to do this is to get the virtual-key code of the character by calling `VkKeyScanEx()` with the character. The high-order bytes of the return value will tell you which modifier keys you need to "press": Control, Alt, and/or Shift; the low-order bytes are the actual virtual-key code.

To get the scan code of the VK, call `MapVirtualKeyEx(vkCode, 0);`

Then it's just a matter of doing the keypress simulation with the information just obtained.

Comment: I'm not sure how do you use this information but you should remember that the result is dependent on the current keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it SendInput() is just a wrapper around calls to mouse_event() and keybd_event() that gurantees that your input doesn't get interspersed with input from the user or other callers.

So I guess the question I have is, have you tried using keybd_event()?

Comment: Yeah, I actually was trying to use keybd_event(), until I noticed that SendInput accepted Unicode characters directly with the KEYEVENTF_UNICODE flag. Since keybd_event() takes a virtual-key code and scan code just like SendInput() does, I wasn't able to figure out how to get keybd_event() to work for me, either.

Comment: Yeah. Some international keyboards use multiple keypresses to 'compose' a single keyevent.  SendInput lets you get that keyevent without having to build (or know) all of the little keypresses that go into it.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be more help that that.  I can point out that scancodes aren't the same thing as the virtual keycodes that they map to, but I presume you already know that.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET all strings are kept as Unicode (UTF-8) strings, internally. You can verify that by converting a string to an array (byte[], NOT char[]!). So you can just ignore anything about scan codes, keyboard layouts and virtual keycodes.

The following works for me in C#/.NET:

```
string myText = "greekcyrillicjapaneseorwhathaveyou"; // can be input via a Forms textbox

char[] Mychars = myText.ToCharArray();

UInt16 uniCode = chars[5]; // if you want to simulate, say, the sixth' char of the string
```

...

```
ki.wScan = unicode

ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
```

...

Comment: .NET strings are UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: This also works for Unicode code points outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, e.g. emojis, although they need to be split into two `char` units. (Except for Notepad++.)